# Type pinyin with tone accent marks on Android

Tags: android, input-method

Is there a input method on Android that allows for typing in pinyin with tone accent marks? Pinyin has the following special characters:

ā ē ī ō ū ǖ Ā Ē Ī Ō Ū Ǖ á é í ó ú ǘ Á É Í Ó Ú Ǘ ǎ ě ǐ ǒ ǔ ǚ Ǎ Ě Ǐ Ǒ Ǔ Ǚ à è ì ò ù ǜ À È Ì Ò Ù Ǜ ü Ü

I'm okay with inserting the special characters either by writing the tone number (1 2 3 4) after the syllable and then having the syllable automatically get the tone diacritic, or long-pressing a letter to select a diacritic version of the letter.

Gboard Chinese does have these diacritic characters, but when you type any other normal letters it will suggest some hanzi for you and not type those letters.

The app should be gratis. I'm using Android 9.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Pinyin Input](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.pinyin) has an English mode which doesn't suggest Chinese characters and still has all the pinyin diacritics from long-press letters. You can disable autocorrect and just type pinyin. I found the default long-press delay of 300 ms too long, so I reduced it to 180 ms. I think it still feels a lot more cumbersome than typing Chinese characters with a typical input method, so I'd probably prefer a method like [pinyinput](https://www.pinyinput.net/) on Windows or [this online tool](https://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/pinyin-editor.html) where you type a number after the syllable to select the tone.